# processing ajax post on the server using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to do something that's very new to me. I've done some digging but what I've come up with only had solutions by using some kind of .aspx page to process forms.

What I'd like to do is send some form input via ajax (I'm using jquery) to the server to be processed by c#.

This is, I believe, a fairly general question. It doesn't have to do with submitting form input specifically, but more about how to send some data to be processed by c# in the backend.

I want to make an ajax POST to a certain page for processing such as this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "****???****",
    data: { name: "Bob", gender: "Male" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var names = response.d;
        alert(names);
    }
});
```

Now, my question is, what kind of file/page can I use for the url value in the above ajax call, that will be able to handle the POSTed data using c#?

All the examples I've seen use a .aspx page that processes the form and sends it to a .cs code-behind page. If possible, I'd like to be able to use something other than an .aspx page.

The site I'm working on is using just HTML as I'm working with angular. Is there any other way I can handle ajax on the server in a way that I can use c#?

To be very specific, I'm trying to setup a registration page where a user puts in their username and password. I need the password to be sent to the server to have a hash and salt created in C#.

Thanks, and please let me know if you need any additional information to continue.

Comment: Are you using the MVC pattern??

Comment: No  I'm not. I'm kind of using it but through angular. I'm not using Microsoft's MVC implementation at all

Comment: I've backed angular pages with a ASP.NET MVC site with actions returning json. The default MVC templates have authentication set-up with the Identity framework or (previously) Simple Membership.

Comment: I'm using WebAPI to hit a database and query and stuff. Could I possibly use one of those context controllers in a similar way to an MVC controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In code behind file:Default.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GenerateHash(string name,string password)
{
         //Write logic to generate hash
}
```

.aspx page

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GenerateHash",
    data: { name: "xxx", password: "xxxx" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var names = response.d;
        alert(names);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey malkam, as part of the question, is the only option I have to use .aspx pages? Is that the only way my site can interact with c# code in the backend?

Comment: You can have a Web API also.Check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms